# PHP does not distinguish between NULL value (empty value) and 0 value (numerical)

Tags: php, sql, null, conditional-statements

I have a PHP conditional in charge of setting $hideZeroValues as FALSE if a field called `ro_capacity` is NULL (if the value returns as empty on the query).

```
if ($result_ro['ro_capacity'] == "") {
    $hideZeroValues="true";
}  
else{
    $hideZeroValues="false";
}
```

Value resulting from `$result_ro['ro_capacity']` is stored on as the value for data-capacity on parent DIV, and the TRUE or FALSE resulting from `$hideZeroValues` conditional is stored on data-zeroValues on child's row.

So if this conditional would work proper, there could be no option for having both `data-capacity=0` and `data-zerovalues="true"`, as 0 is a value, not an empty value, not a NULL. But as you see in these two divs, it happens: first one is OK (`data-capacity=""` and `data-zeroValues="true"`), but on the second one it keep setting TRUE even when the query gives a value back (0).

```
<div id="92" class="tableRow" title="Aula prueba" data-id="92" data-capacity="">
<span class="tableContentText centerText" data-zerovalues="true">-</span>
</div>

<div id="91" class="tableRow" title="Aula prueba" data-id="91" data-capacity="0">
<span class="tableContentText centerText" data-zerovalues="true">-</span>
</div>
```

The third one, with a 12 value, works fine (the problem only happens with 0 and NULL, not wth any other numeric value:

```
<div id="93" class="tableRow" title="Aula prueba" data-id="91" data-capacity="12">
<span class="tableContentText centerText" data-zerovalues="false">-</span>
</div>
```

I have tried also:

```
if ($result_ro['ro_capacity'] === "") { $hideZeroValues="true"; }
```

and

```
if (is_null($result_ro['ro_capacity']) {    $hideZeroValues="true"; }
```

Comment: have you tried empty() ?

Comment: Hi karlingen thanks 4 your attention. in which way can I use empty() to make php understand 0 as a not-null value?

Comment: if(empty($result_ro['ro_capacity']) && $result_ro['ro_capacity'] !== 0)

Comment: At least worked, thank you

Comment: no worries. I've added it as an answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because 0 is evaluated to false in PHP.

Try this approach:

```
if(empty($result_ro['ro_capacity']) && $result_ro['ro_capacity'] !== 0)
```